# How to enable screensaver in windows 7 when in locked screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, screensaver

How can I make the screensaver start automatically after some time when in the LOCKED screen?

I don't mean the logon dialog screen, but the locked screen.

Comment: The old way is to change the screen saver settings of the system user. You can either use some "Run as" tools to run desktop.cpl as system or change the registry directly.